# Как посчитать количество элементов в каждой строке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Надо создать новую колонку, в которую поместить сумму элементов "Да" из предыдущих колонок:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'Да', 1: 'Да', 2: 'Да'},
                    'B': {0: 'Да', 1: 'Нет', 2: 'Да'},
                    'C': {0: 'Нет', 1: 'Да', 2: 'Нет'},
                    'D': {0: 'Да', 1: 'Да', 2: 'Нет'}})

    A   B   C   D
0   Да  Да  Нет Да
1   Да  Нет Да  Да
2   Да  Да  Нет Нет
```

Посчитать элементы в одной строке получается:

```
x = (df.loc[1, 'A': 'D'] == 'Да').sum()
print(x)
3
```

А вот пройтись циклом не получается:

```
df.loc[:, 'E'] = [(df.loc[i, 'B':'D'] == 'Да').sum() for i in range(len(df) + 1)]
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> KeyError: 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такие задачи решаются в Pandas без циклов:

```
df["res"] = df.loc[:, :"D"].eq("Да").sum(axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [272]: df
Out[272]:
    A    B    C    D  res
0  Да   Да  Нет   Да    3
1  Да  Нет   Да   Да    3
2  Да   Да  Нет  Нет    2
```

Comment: Да! Согласен, надо. И хочется)))))